# pattern recognition with some features in time series data

Tags: time-series, array-signal-processing

I am trying to capture peaks in a time series data which has some predefined feature.
Here is a snapshot of time-series data (Time series data with peaks)

[image: im1]

In this time-series I want to detect peaks that look like peaks like this need to be detected in time series.

[image: im2]

What would be the best approach to find such peaks in time series?
I tried with correlation but it is good for finding peaks but not the features embedded in it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: correlation does seem to be the right tool. Did you normalize by the energy of the segment you're correlating against your prototype?

Comment: I normalized it by subtracting the mean and then divide it by variance. Should i divide by the energy of the signal and then corelate?

Comment: no, by the energy of the *segment* you're considering.